# How to iterate efficiently the linear fractional transformation sending $i$, $-1$, $-i$ to $1$, $2$, $3$ respectively

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

> Let $z_{k}=e^{ik\pi/2}$ for every $k$. Let $T$ denote the linear fractional transformation that maps the points $z_{1}$, $z_{2}$, $z_{3}$ into the points $1$, $2$, $3$ respectively.
>
> Let $T^m(z)$ denote the image of $z$ after applying $m$ times the transformation $T$, i.e.
> $$T^m(z)=(T \circ T \circ T \circ \cdots \circ T )(z)$$
> Find $T(z)$ in closed form. Find $T^m(z_{0})$ for every nonnegative integer $m$.

**What I tried:** Suppose that $$T(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$$

How can I get $T^m(1)$ in short time?

Is there any trick to get $T(z) $ and $T^m(1)$ in short time ?

Comment: I don't think there is a bilinear transformation that sends $i,-1,-i$ to $1,2,3$ respectively. There is a mobius transformation that does it, but it is neither linear nor bilinear. By the way, what does "bilinear transformation" mean when the is only one argument?

Comment: There is a transformation of the form $T(z)=\frac{az + b}{cz +d }$. I call this bilinear transformation .

Comment: Well, that transformation is nowhere near any form of linearity. Why do you say in your question that you're looking for a bilinear $T$?

Comment: I mean  quotient of two linear transformations .this is called Linear fractional transformation or bilinear transformation .

Comment: That's not what "bilinear" usually means. Usually, is used about a transformation that takes _two_ arguments, and behaves linearly for each of them separately. But ok.

Comment: if $w=\frac{az+b}{cz+d} \Rightarrow azw + bz+ cw+ d =0 ,$ that's why the author of the book which i study from call this bilinear snce it is linear in both w , z.

Comment: "the book which i study" - could you tell us what book this is, for reference?

Comment: Indeed the powers of a linear fractional transformation $T$ can be computed easily. In the general case, considering the fixed points $u$ and $v$ of $T$, a simple computation shows that $$\frac{T(z)-u}{T(z)-v}=\alpha\frac{z-u}{z-v}$$ for some given $\alpha$. This gives readily  $$\frac{T^m(z)-u}{T^m(z)-v}=\alpha^m\frac{z-u}{z-v}$$ for every $m$, from which $T^m(z)$ can be deduced.

Comment: Another way to get easily the powers associated to the iteration of $f$ defined by $f(z):=\dfrac{(2 -i)z -2 - i} {z-1}=\dfrac{az +b} {cz+d}$ is to get its coefficients by working (using a classical isomorphism) with the powers of $\pmatrix{(2 -i)& (-2 - i)\\1&-1}=\pmatrix{a& b\\c&d}$

Answer (score 0):

First find $T$. The result is
$$T(z)={2+i-(2-i)z\over1-z}\ .$$
Then find the two fixed points $z_1$, $z_2$ of $T$. They are
$$z_1={1\over2}\bigl(3+\sqrt{5}-i(1+\sqrt{5})\bigr),\qquad z_2={1\over2}\bigl(3-\sqrt{5}-i(1-\sqrt{5})\bigr)\ .$$
Introduce a new "complex coordinate"
$$w:={z-z_1\over z-z_2}\ ,$$
and compute the expression $\hat T$ of $T$ in this new coordinate. The fixed points now are $w_1=0$ and $w_2=\infty$, hence $\hat T$ is of the form $\hat T(w)=\lambda w$ for some complex constant $\lambda$. It follows that $\hat T{}^n(w)=\lambda^n w$.

It's a long way to go.